# In R; I would like to do something in R rather than excel because excel can't handle the calculation. In excel the calculation is: =A2+SUM($B$2:B2)

Tags: r, excel

I want col c `phys_pos` to be the value in col a `position` plus the accumulative value of col b `length`. In excel the calculation is: `=A2+SUM($B$2:B2)`, but excel can't handle such a lot of data. Thanks all.

The data I would like:

```
position    length  phys_pos
12  45  57
97  0   142
135 0   180
498 0   543
512 0   557
16  67  128
76  0   188
89  0   201
101 0   213
152 0   264
3   103 218
19  0   234
76  0   291
88  0   303
```

Comment: Calculating the cumulative sum is trivial in R. Do some research.

Comment: @Roland. Thanks a lot for your suggestions, I am grateful. I will get my head around R, I do want to, but find it harder than you guys. Eventually I will be able to help people on here too I hope!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Look into `dplyr` https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html

```
install.packages("dplyr")

library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% mutate(phys_pos=cumsum(length)+position)
```

I am assuming your `data.frame` is named `df`

Or with base R

```
df$phys_pos <- cumsum(df$length) + df$position
```

Comment: Why do you recommend dplyr here? You can do it just as easily with base R.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming your data is stored in a dataframe called "dat":

```
acc <- 0
for(i in 1:nrow(dat)){
  acc <- acc + dat[i,"length"]
  dat[i,"phys_pos"] <- dat[i,"position"]+acc
}
```

This is simple stuff. If you would do some tutorials you could learn to do it on your own pretty fast.

Comment: Do not use a loop for this. Use the `cumsum` function.

Comment: I agree, that looks cleaner and more efficient. Use the above answer.

Comment: @Ulli Schmid. Thanks a lot for your suggestions, I am grateful. I will get my head around R, I do want to, but find it harder than you guys. Eventually I will be able to help people on here too I hope!